# How to generalize combinations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a combinations with 3 factors:

```
{a1,m1,c1}
{a1,m1,c2}
{a1,m2,c1}
{a2,m1,c1}
{a2,m1,c2}
```

Now I want to "compress" these 5 expressions into as few expressions as possible, in this case 2 is the minimum:

```
{{c1,c2},{m1},{a1,a2}} 
{{c1},{m2},{a1}}
```

As we can see, we can easily generate original combinations from the compressed expressions.

My question is how do I generalize an algorithm to compress the combinations to fewest expressions?

I have more complex case with 4 or 5 factors.

I believe there is an existing algorithm for doing this, could you share a link to the algorithm?

Update:

A more general case with 2 factors:

Using

```
{a1,a2,a3} {c1,c2,c3}
```

we can generate

```
{a1,c1} {a1,c2} {a1,c3}, {a2,c1} {a2,c2} {a2,c3} {a3,c1} {a3,c2} {a3,c3}
```

How can I deduce

```
{{a1,a2,a3},{c1,c2,c3}}
```

from

```
{a1,c1} {a1,c2} {a1,c3}, {a2,c1} {a2,c2} {a2,c3} {a3,c1} {a3,c2} {a3,c3}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "compress" in this case? It's pretty unclear from your post how you chose those particular combinations. Is it that you want to be able to generate all of your original lists using, for instance, `Tuples[{{a1, a2}, {m1}, {c1, c2}}]` and `Tuples[{{a1},{m2},{c1}}]` with as small a generating set as possible (two in this case)?

Comment: So, the `result` of the algorithm is meant to be the "inverse" of `Union @@ (Tuples /@ result)`?

Comment: @sfdcnoob: Very interesting question. Is there a reason why you tagged it by "linear-algebra"? That might shed some light on the background of this question and mights also be help to develop an algorithm. Moreover, is there any a priori knowledge about the input data?

Comment: this is a coding assignment for my work. I need to build a configuration file. I felt it's somewhat similar to matrix multiplication.

Comment: There is not always a unique way to "compress" the data. For example, {a1,b1} {a1,b2} {a2,b1} can be "compressed" as {{a1},{b1,b2}} {{a2},{b1}} or {{a1,a2},{b1}} {{a1},{b2}}

Comment: yes, if I sort the input and apply an algorithm, I should be able to get same result every time.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to interpret you list of tuples as a sum of products, and to leverage [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) to group terms:

Let

```
tuples = {
  {a1, m1, c1},
  {a1, m1, c2},
  {a1, m2, c1},
  {a2, m1, c1},
  {a2, m1, c2}
 };
```

Now we can transform it into a sum of products and simplify:

```
Plus @@ Times @@@ tuples
(* a1 c1 m1 + a2 c1 m1 + a1 c2 m1 + a2 c2 m1 + a1 c1 m2 *)

% // FullSimplify
(* (a1 + a2) (c1 + c2) m1 + a1 c1 m2 *)

(* replace Plus and Times with List again *)
% // ReplaceAll[Times | Plus -> List]
(* {{{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}, m1}, {a1, c1, m2}} *)

(* clean the result up a bit by ensuring that also the one-element cases are lists *)
% // Map[Flatten@*List, #, {2}] &
(* {{{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}, {m1}}, {{a1}, {c1}, {m2}}} *)
```

The same works for your other example:

```
tuples2 = {{a1, c1}, {a1, c2}, {a1, c3}, {a2, c1},
 {a2, c2}, {a2, c3}, {a3, c1}, {a3, c2}, {a3, c3}};

Map[Flatten@*List, FullSimplify[Plus @@ Times @@@ tuples2] /. Times | Plus -> List, {2}]
(* {{{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}, {m1}}, {{a1}, {c1}, {m2}}} *)
```

Of course, this might not work in all cases, and it will not respect the order of terms, but depending on what you need, this is already good enough.

#### Order preserving version

In case the order of the elements is important, here is an order-preserving version:

```
(
  SortBy[First@*First] /@
   Map[
    Flatten@*List,
    FullSimplify[Plus @@ Times @@@ MapIndexed[Construct] /@ tuples2] /. Times | Plus -> List,
    {2}
    ]
  )[[All, All, All, 0]]
```

The basic idea is the same, but this time we keep track of the initial positions of the elements in the lists, and use those to sort the elements again after simplification.

Comment: thank you! this looks elegant, but can I use this library in golang?

Comment: Wow this is brilliant! For preserving the order you could also have in the first line `Plus @@ NonCommutativeMultiply @@@ tuples`, in the second line `FullSimplify[%, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. u1_ ** v_ + u2_ ** v_ -> (u1 + u2) ** v &, # /. u_ ** v1_ + u_ ** v2_ -> u ** (v1 + v2) &}]`, and in the third line `% // ReplaceAll[NonCommutativeMultiply | Plus -> List]`.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the suggestion to use `NonCommutativeMultiply`, but unfortunately I can't get it to work for some reason. (Not even by directly copying your code)

Comment: @sfdcnoob What do you mean by that? What library? What does golang have to do with it?

Comment: @LukasLang you're right it doesn't work, I hadn't tried enough examples. I can't figure out the necessary `TransformationFunctions` to make it work. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that recursively searches for the largest subset combination that is contained in the set:

```
cover[{}] = {};
cover[L_List] := Module[{u, n, uu, s, t, a, LL},
  (* list the unique elements in each column *)
  u = Union /@ Transpose[L];
  (* the number of columns *)
  n = Length[u];
  (* all subsets of the elements in u *)
  uu = Subsets[#, {1, ∞}] & /@ u;
  (* all combinations of such subsets and the resulting elements *)
  s = Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ uu, 1], n - 1];
  (* pick out those subset combinations that are fully contained in L *)
  t = Select[s, SubsetQ[L, Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ #], n - 1]] &];
  (* pick the largest one *)
  a = First[MaximalBy[t, Length[Flatten[#]] &, 1]];
  (* which elements of L aren't covered yet? *)
  LL = Complement[L, Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ a, 1], n - 1]];
  (* recurse *)
  Prepend[cover[LL], a]]
```

test:

```
cover[{{a1, m1, c1}, {a1, m1, c2}, {a1, m2, c1}, {a2, m1, c1}, {a2, m1, c2}}]
```

> {{{a1, a2}, {m1}, {c1, c2}}, {{a1}, {m2}, {c1}}}

```
cover[{{a1, c1}, {a1, c2}, {a1, c3}, {a2, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a2, c3}, {a3, c1}, {a3, c2}, {a3, c3}}]
```

> {{{a1, a2, a3}, {c1, c2, c3}}}

Same but with the last element removed:

```
cover[{{a1, c1}, {a1, c2}, {a1, c3}, {a2, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a2, c3}, {a3, c1}, {a3, c2}}]
```

> {{{a1, a2}, {c1, c2, c3}}, {{a3}, {c1, c2}}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works but needs a lot of memory
`a` in your example is `{{a1,a2},{m1,m2},{c1,c2}}` and
`s` in your example is `{{a1,m1,c1},{a1,m1,c2},{a1,m2,c1},{a2,m1,c1},{a2,m1,c2}}`

since this needs a lot of memory here is how it works on `a={{a1,a2},{c1,c2}}`

```
a = {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}};
s = {{a1, c2}, {a2, c2}};
First@Select[Subsets[Tuples[Rest@Subsets[#]&/@a]],Union@Flatten[Tuples/@#,1]==s&]
```

> {{{a1, a2}, {c2}}}

for

```
s = {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}};
```

> {{{a1}, {c1}}, {{a2}, {c2}}}